# How to remove the "Suggest documentation" hint in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Since version 2023.2 Beta, PhpStorm started adding this *Suggest documentation* hint every time I click on a docblock:

[image: Suggest documentation PhpStorm]

How can I disable it? I couldn't find it in the settings.

Comment: Looking at the icon -- it has to be the new AI module. Search for **AI Assistant** in the settings/plugins. _(cannot provide exact steps because I have not tried the EAP builds myself yet)_

Comment: Check these blog posts: 1) https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2023/06/ai-features-in-phpstorm-phpstorm-2023-2-eap-5/ and 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/06/ai-assistant-in-jetbrains-ides/

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, found it, I'm adding it as an answer.

Comment: @LazyOne Actually my answer doesn't work, I'm still getting the hint.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDE (or at very least closing and reopening the project again) after disabling it? **P.S.** That Intentions place seems to be the right place (I'd look there as well). **P.P.S.** If that does not help, what about the actual AI plugin. Is there any? Because I would expect such stuff to come as a plugin (just like Machine Learning code completion / search results has).

Comment: @LazyOne Still happens after clearing cache / restarting. However, there is indeed an "AI assistant" plugin which can be disabled, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Uncheck "AI Assistant" under Settings > Editor > Intentions:</s>

[image: AI Assistant Intentions]

Edit: actually this doesn't work, I'm still getting the hint.

What works is **disabling the *AI Assistant* plugin entirely**:

[image: AI Assistant Plugin]